# jQuery offset().top is browser incompatible?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to position an element right under some other element, but I've ran in an issue where offset() returns different values for IE and other browsers, when the page is scrolled down.

IE returns position relative to the top of the visible area (i.e. declining when you scroll down), and Firefox and Chrome always return the same value, regardless of the scrolling (which I presume is a much better behavior).

Just to clarify: what bothers me is that if none of the elements parents are relatively positioned, then offset() and position() return different values for IE, depending on how far you've scrolled down, but this is never mentioned in jQuery docs. Why is that so? Is there any way around it, that doesn't require any change of the html structure (for instance, I want to reuse one datepicker for many fields, just repositioning it slightly).

Has anyone run into the same issue?

Comment: Provide a code sample that re-creates the problem.  I have never experienced any issues with jQuery `offset`.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/victordas/5tMWT/1/), test by dragging red div all around.

HTML

```
<div id="hook"></div>
<div id="hanger"></div>
```

CSS

```
#hook {
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color:red;
    position: absolute;
    cursor: move;
}
#hanger {
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color:purple;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Javascript

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    var top = $('#hook').offset().top + $('#hook').height()+20;
    var left = $('#hook').offset().left;

    $('#hanger').css('top', top);
    $('#hanger').css('left', left);

    $('#hook').draggable({
        start: function(){
            $('#hanger').toggle();
        },
        stop: function(){
                var top = $('#hook').offset().top + $('#hook').height()+20;
                var left = $('#hook').offset().left;

                $('#hanger').css('top', top);
                $('#hanger').css('left', left);

                $('#hanger').toggle();
        }
        });
});
```

Comment: In what does that answer the question?

Answer (score 0):

Elaborating on griegs answer you can can append it to the same containing DOM element and then use `.position()` instead of `.offset()` as it will reference the position based on the parent, rather than the document. Might give you better results.

http://api.jquery.com/position/

### Edit

grieg deleted his answer, this is what he said:

> No but I use Append to append items after other items.
>   So if your elements are in say a div you would append
>   the new elements to the Div which should make them
>   appear at the bottom

Comment: Well, I'm trying to absolutely position a DatePicker, and parent() and offset() return same values. I just don't want to check for IE, I want some cross-browser compatible way, but can't think of any.

Comment: Not `.parent()`., `.position()`, it returns the position based upon the DOM element, so if they're both in the same `div`, relevant to that `div`.

Answer (score 0):

This should work, although it may require the parent element of `elem` to be relatively-positioned...

```
var elem = $("#elementToShowCalenderUnder");
var pos = elem.position();
$("#yourCalender").css({
  position: "absolute",
  left: pos.left() + "px";
  top: pos.top() + elem.height() + 5 + "px";
}).insertAfter(elem);
```

Comment: That doesn't help. Maybe it works, but it's way too much structural change, and position() is still going to return invalid values.

Comment: @HeavyWave Well... This works.  Not sure what else you're looking for.  I've never had any problems with `offset` before, either.

Comment: It doesn't change the fact that position() and offset() return invalid values if the parent is not positioned relatively.

Comment: @HeavyWave Quite frankly, I have no idea what makes you think the values are "invalid"!  It is returning exactly what it is supposed to return, according to the API.

Answer (score 0):

IE8 does not have the pageX or pageY attributes, which give you the position of the event relative to the page and not the browser window, to work around this, you can calculate your position my inspecting  the scroll position as in the following code example:

```
...
var view = this;
var currEl = evt.currentTarget.graphic.element; //evt.toElement;
//Determine the coordinates to offset the positioning of the context menu by
var posx = 0;
var posy = 0;
if (evt.pageX || evt.pageY) {
    posx = evt.pageX;
    posy = evt.pageY;
} else if (evt.clientX || evt.clientY) { //IE8 & 9 don't have pageX or pageY
    posx = evt.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft + document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
    posy = evt.clientY + document.body.scrollTop + document.documentElement.scrollTop;
}
var atPos = (posx - $(currEl).offset().left) + " " + (posy - $(currEl).offset().top);
...
```

Comment: In what does that answer the question?

Comment: Looked like the asker of the question was getting unexpected behavior in IE  related to handling scroll events and positioning and asking for a workaround.  This is a workaround I've used to to reliably resolve positioning in IE8 & 9 IE.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `.offset()`, you may use:

`$("#div_id").get(0).getBoundingClientRect().top + scroll_value`

`scroll_value` above is `$("#enclosing_div_with_scrollbar_id").scrollTop()` value
where `enclosing)_div_with_scrollbar_id` is the id of div which encloses the initial `div_id` and has a scroll bar.

If enclosing div is body or html, then use:

`scroll_value= ($("body").scrollTop() || $("html").scrollTop())`

(two values because Chrome and Firefox respond differently to `.scrollTop()` function)

Answer (score -1):

```
var el = $("myElement");
var position = el.position();
//PREVENT SCROLLING.
 var parentScroll =  el.offsetParent();
 position.top += parentScroll.scrollTop();
 position.left +=parentScroll.scrollLeft();
```

Comment: In what does that answer the question?